# Split data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table which basically contain State name, City name, and Commune name (not sure if that's a thing in some countries) and I also have ID of the state.

[image]

I made another design for the table, like this:

State

- State_ID
- State_name

City

- City_ID
- City_name
- State_ID

Commune

- Commune_ID
- Commune_name
- City_ID

I managed to insert the State and the City in the new table... but I can't find a way to insert the Communes.

Sample Data (from the old table):

```
1   Adrar   Adrar   Adrar   01
2   Adrar   Adrar   Bouda   01
3   Adrar   Adrar   Ouled Ahmed Tammi   01
4   Adrar   Aougrout    Aougrout    01
5   Adrar   Aougrout    Deldoul 01
6   Adrar   Aougrout    Metarfa 01
```

So what I basically want to do here is to Insert the third column (Deldoul, Metarfa) to my new Commune table...except that I have no ID for the City. I only have the name. I tried to get the IDs from my new "City" table like this, but that didn't work:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.Commune
SELECT commune,
(SELECT id_state from DB2.dbo.State
 INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.TabOld
 ON Daira = City_name)
 FROM [DB1].[dbo].TabOld
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The title don't describe your question. Maybe the title 'Split data from one table to some tables' is more evocative. And can you describe the column in the old table? I don't see the city name and state name in the image.

Comment: @Vernou Apologies.
`Wilaya` = State name
`Daira` = City name
`Commune` = Commune name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sub-query you can use external column directly (no need join on external table) like :

```sql
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.Commune (Commune_Name, City_ID)
SELECT commune,
    (SELECT City_ID 
    from DB2.dbo.City
    join DB2.dbo.State on State.State_ID=City.State_ID
    where City_name=Daira and Willaya=State_Name)
FROM [DB1].[dbo].TabOld
```